# How do I create "beveled" T-intersection traces in Eagle CAD?

Tags: eaglecad, routing

Frequently it is convenient to route traces on a PCB such that some other traces or pads are at right angles to a common bus. However, this creates "T" intersections which have 90° angles, which can potentially create problems during the copper etching process. (Such as acid pockets that decrease the effective trace width.)

[image: T-intersection without bevel]

Using the "Route" tool, I can't add additional traces at 45° angles to create a "beveled" intersection, and Eagle doesn't seem to have any option to adjust how intersections are handled.

How can I create a "T" intersection that incorporates some sort of bevel to avoid the 90° angles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right below the "Route" tool is a "Wire" tool, which you are probably familiar with from the schematic editor.

You can use this to create arbitrary traces, such as short 45° segments to create a bevel:

[image: Eagle CAD Creating a Bevel]

You might have to change the grid pitch or hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> to start the wire at an appropriate location near the intersection. Make sure the wire bend style allows the angle or curve you want.

With just two wire segments you can create a simple 45° beveled "T" intersection like this:

[image: T-intersection with bevel]